# Copy database schema to an existing database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm using  Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio.
I currently have an existing database with data in it, which I will call DatabaseProd
And I have a second database with data used for testing, so the data isn't exactly correct nor up to date. I will call this database DatabaseDev.

However DatabaseDev now contains newly added tables and newly added columns,etc etc.

I would like to copy this new schema from DatabaseDev to DatabaseProd while keeping the DatabaseProd's Data.

Ex.
DatabaseProd contains 2 tables
TableA with column ID and Name
TableB with column ID and jobName
and these tables contains data that I would like to keep

DatabaseDev contains 3 tables
TableA with column ID ,Name and phoneNum
TableB with column ID and jobName
TableC with column ID and document
and these tables contains Data that I dont need

Copy DatabaseDev Schema to DatabaseProd but keep the data from DatabaseProd
So DatabaseProd after the copy would look like this
TableA with column ID ,Name and phoneNum
TableB with column ID and jobName
TableC with column ID and document
But the tables would contain it's original Data.

Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: I would recommend using something like Visual Studio's database comparison tools.

Comment: But how would I make the copy?

Comment: It doesn't make a copy, it generates a script. The tool is capable of comparing the databases, scripting the changes, and then you can modify that script as necessary before executing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Red-Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/), this will allow you to compare both DB's and generate a script to run on the source DB.  You have to pay for a license, but you will get a `14-day trial period`.

This tool, along with [Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) and two tools I always insist on with new roles as they speed up development time, and minimise human error.

Also, a good **tip** when using SQL compare - if you need to generate a `rollback script`, then you can edit the project (after creating your `rollout script`), switch the source and destination around and this will create a script which will return the schema back to it's original state if the `rollout script` fails.  However, be **very careful** when doing this, and **don't select synchronize with sql compare**, rather generate a script, [see image](http://www.red-gate.com/support/SQL_Data_Compare/help/9.0/sc_w-ex-1_sync_wiz_1.gif). I can't upload an image, but I have linked to one here - you can see the two options to select Generate Script / Sync using SQL compare.

Comment: This tool seems to be good, but does it also transfer the Data? because it seems to be doing so. Am I selecting some bad options?

Comment: You can also use Red-Gate SQL Data Compare, and this will compare based on key fields and create a script for inserts, delete or updates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just generate a database script which is just for schema only no data will added to that script.

Also you need to just select the third table while creating or generating the database script and run that script to your production server database it will create a new table (table 3 in your case) without any data.

For more information about how to create a database script please follow the below link:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/07/sql-server-2008-2008-r2-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-data-schema-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this will simply create a new database with the Schema of DatabaseDEV on my Production server? The Data in DatabaseProd will not be in it. I want to have the DatabaseProd data in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need an ALTER TABLE statement

```
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD PhoneNum Varchar(10) --Insert variable of choice here
```

Looked like no changes to TableB

Add TableC

```
CREATE TABLE TableC (ColumnID int, Document Varvhar(50))
```

DO you need to copy constraints, Indexes or triggers over?