# How can I move data from SQL Server (localdb) to Azure SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have been developing an application with VS2012 on my local machine. I created a database there and it uses:

```
(localdb)\v11.0 (SQL Server 11.0)
```

I would now like to start using the cloud version of SQL Server. I already have an account set up but how can I move my data from my local PC into the new database?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here for moving schema and data from one DB to another...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873644/copy-database-schema-to-an-existing-database/18874929#18874929

Comment: Thanks but moving data to Azure is very different so I'm hoping for someone who can give me some tips on how to do that.

Comment: I haven't used this myself, but the following link seems like it would meet your needs:
http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/

Comment: If you are just looking for a one time move of your database to SQL Azure, I would agree with HitsKey that the SQL Azure migration wizard is a great tool to help you do this. If you need to ultimately key your SQL Azure database in sync (bi-directionally) with your local SQL Server database, you might want to take a look at [SQL Azure Data Sync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456371.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone needs the answer to this, so I had the same issue. Usually I could copy paste the data using the Localdb and SSMS which was the easiest way to do this, but I had 1 table containing binary data so couldn't copy them across.

Apparently there's a Data Comparison menu when you right click on the database in your SQL Server Object Explorer, which compares the local database to the azure SQL server database and it worked like a charm. It connects to the Azure SQL database and compares the data and you can choose what to synchronize across to the target database.

Comment: That's not a synchronization mechanism at all, and the slowest (and most expensive) possible way of copying data. First it *downloads* all the data from Azure SQL, incurring outbound bandwidth charges, and then generates scripts for the differences. As the comments show, there's both a migration wizard *and* an actual Data Sync service. You can also upload a backup of your database. The Export Data Wizard in SSMS can create an SSIS package that copies data from one database to another, including Azure SQL.

Comment: Yeah that's true, what I needed was to copy across a few rows that I had as part of the testing of the platform. It's definitely not a way to synchronize large databases or migrate them to Azure. It did the job for me.

Comment: Only by accident, which is why this is not a good answer. There are several SO questions asking why  the pasted data is truncated, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897950/how-do-you-view-all-text-from-an-ntext-or-nvarcharmax-in-ssms). SSMS truncates long fields in grid results